# Do I have any way to connect to a Hyper-V Server using a PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

To connect to a Hyper-V host from Hyper-V Manager, right-click Hyper-V Manager in the left pane, and then click Connect to Server.

Do I have any way to connect to a Hyper-V Server using a PowerShell command?

If so please include code (example my VM name is VM_1), thanks so much!

Comment: You would need to define what you mean by *connect*, but have you looked at the documentation? [Working with Hyper-V and Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/try-hyper-v-powershell) and [Virtual Machine automation and management using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct)

Comment: This question may not belong on this site. Perhaps more geared toward server fault?

Answer (score 0):

Install Hyper-V Powershell module from Windows Features.

```
Get-VM -ComputerName <servernames>
```

You will get list of VMs running under Hyper-V hosts.